# virtualenv: command not found after installed with Pip on Mac

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pip, homebrew

I am trying to install VirtualEnv on my Mac. I have installed Python and Pip with brew. After running 
pip install virtualenv
When I try to use it I am getting:

```
bash: "virtualenv: command not found"
```

I am unsure where virtualenv has been installed. 
My PATH environment variable contains:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

I am using: Mac Os 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue.

What you need to do is to add the pathname of where the package was installed to your .profile file. Look to see where the virtualenv package was installed into - in my case it was /Users/ianloke/Library/Python/2.7/bin. Then append this pathname to the PATH environment variable.