# python : Cant use packages installed outside site-packages

Tags: python, unix

I have python 2.7.5 and i installed some packages as

`python setup.py install --user`

so this installed packages in

`/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

and then i updated the PYTHONPATH variable to be

`/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages,/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

but now if i try to do

`virtualenv`

which is the package i installed, i get

`bash: virtualenv: command not found`

how can i use the `virtualenv` package that has been installed outside of site-packages?

**EDIT**

here is my sys.path

```
'', '/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0.dev0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.2.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

but i still get the command not found error

also, here is my $PATH

`/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: did you restart your terminal? you might need to edit PATH, not PYTHONPATH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtualenv: command not found after installed with Pip on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568718/virtualenv-command-not-found-after-installed-with-pip-on-mac)

Comment: i tried the solution on that question but i still get the command not found. even after restarting and adding `export PATH=$PATH:/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/users/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to my `.profile`

Answer (score 0):

You can append the value of the path to your new library in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

But you can also append a path in runtime.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/dir1/dir2/libs')
```

Comment: can you run the following command to see if your site_packages location is the right one.

    import site; site.getsitepackages()